# How to plot two formula of which on is dependent on the other?

Tags: plotting

suppose the simple example

y[x_] := 1 + x

z[r_] := 1 + r + y[x]

Is this so far correct?

How to plot then z?

Plot[z[r], {r, 1, 2}, {y[x], 1, 2}] doesnt work for me.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The function `z` is dependent on `r` *and* `y` or `x`. Thus you can e.g. write

```
z[r_,x_]:=1+r+y[x]
```

and then use Plot3D or ContourPlot

```
Plot3D[z[r,x],{r,1,2},{x,1,2}]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but I may specifiy the question::

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[x, y, z]
y[x_] := 1 + x
z[r_] := 1 + r + y[x]

ContourPlot[{z[r], y[x]}, {r, -2, 2}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.8, 0.8}]]
```

[image]